# Ambiguous Overload in Scala 3 with Varargs

Tags: scala, overloading, variadic-functions, scala-3

I have the following code.

```scala
object example {

  def foo(a: Any) = "Object"

  def foo(a: String, args: String*) = "String"

  def main() = {
    println(foo("ABC")) // Should print "String"
  }

}
```

In Scala 2, this code works fine. When I call `foo` with a single string argument, both overloads are valid but the `String` one is more specific, so it gets called. In Scala 3, this is ambiguous.

```
-- [E051] Reference Error: overloads.scala:9:12 --------------------------------------------------------------------
9 |    println(foo("ABC"))
  |            ^^^
  |            Ambiguous overload. The overloaded alternatives of method foo in object example with types
  |             (a: String, args: String*): String
  |             (a: Any): String
  |            both match arguments (("ABC" : String))
```

The equivalent code (two overloads, one of them more specific and having a vararg parameter) also works in Java. What exactly changed in Scala 3 to make this particular call ambiguous? Is this behavior intended? And how can I tell Scala which overload to call in this case?

---

For what it's worth, I am well aware method overloading is strongly discouraged in Scala. In my actual code, I'm interfacing with a Java builder class that has an overloaded `.append` method, so I have no control over the function signatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is mentioned in [this PR](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/9732), in particular in [this comment](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/9732#issuecomment-688458407). I don't know if that will be "fixed" or if it's exactly as intended.

Note that the following is *not* ambiguous:

```scala
def foo(s: String)
def foo(a: String, other: String*)
foo("fine!")
```

With `def foo(s: Any)`, you can explicitly select one overload or the other like this:

```scala
foo("fine": Any) // calls foo(Any)
foo("fine", Nil: _*) // calls foo(String, String*) with an empty vararg
```

*PS: I wouldn't say that overloading is "strongly discouraged", but we must be careful and admit that some cases are ambiguous, to the compiler and to humans. It's not obvious to me which definition `foo("")` should refer to, so it's not completely crazy to be more explicit in that case.*

Comment: Hm... that's very interesting. I had convinced myself that the second `foo` in my example was the "obvious" choice, but after reading that PR I see a reasonable argument for either one. "Ambiguous" is fair, I'll grant. Thanks!