# Scala 2 overload resolution with varargs and Object

Tags: scala, overloading, scala-2.13

I am trying to understand the following behavior in Scala 2.13.10 with respect to method overloading selection.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
object Test {
  def func(v: AnyRef*) = { println("varargs") }
  def func(v: Map[String, AnyRef]) = { println("map") }

  def jfunc(v: Object*) = { println("varargs") }
  def jfunc(v: java.util.Map[java.lang.String, Object]) = { println("map") }
}

val strMap: Map[String, String] = Map("test" -> "test")

Test.func("test") \\ varargs
Test.func(strMap) \\ map

Test.jfunc("test") \\ varargs
Test.jfunc(strMap.asJava) \\varargs not map
Test.jfunc(strMap.asInstanceOf[Map[String, AnyRef]].asJava) \\ map
```

I am wondering why the explicit cast to `asInstanceOf[Map[String, AnyRef]]` is required to get the correct version of `jfunc`.

In scala 3.2.2 the explicit cast to `asInstanceOf[Map[String, AnyRef]]` is not required and the output is

```
varargs
map
varargs
map
map
```

Note: I cannot change the method `jfunc` as it is coming from an external library.

Comment: [Semi-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72469040/ambiguous-overload-in-scala-3-with-varargs), though that post is about overload resolution failing in Scala 3.

Comment: There are changes in overload resolution in Scala 3 https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/overload-resolution.html But I can't see anything specific to varargs there